# Terminology: Central binomial coefficients?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Is there a special terminology for the binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}$ which distinguishes them from the central binomial coefficients $\binom{2n}{n}?$

Comment: FWIW, OEIS https://oeis.org/A001405 calls them just "binomial(n, floor(n/2))". I do not see any "generic" name in the comments there, although there are many descriptions related to specific applications.